# How to access domains via IP using nginx?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I'm currently working on switching my webserver from Cent OS running Apache2 and Cpanel to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running nginx without a GUI (unless I can find a good one).

One thing I haven't been able to find any information on is how to setup temporary URL's to access a domain before pointing the DNS at my server.

Cpanel creates 'temporary' URLs when you create a new domain like so: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~somedomain.com

I'd like to achieve the same thing using Ubuntu 12.04 and nginx. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

I'm currently doing my homework on the location{} block of a server{} block, but I'm wondering if anyone can provide an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK cpanel offers temporary URLs based on Apache Mod_Userdir (ip_address/~user) module.
So, your URL would be xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~someuser

This can help you http://wiki.nginx.org/UserDir

Or you can simply use file [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29), this way faster than others.